# Authenticating with MongoDB from JavaScript file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to write a MongoDB script as part of automating customer data deletion in accordance with GDPR (current process is manual), but I'm having problems authenticating from the script. Authentication works perfectly from the command line, but not from a script.

I'm not certain which mechanism I should use, but since there are only two that don't require external files (which I don't use in the command line), I figured I'd try both.

When running from the command line, this is the command I use:

```
$ mongo -u [adminusr] -p '[adminpwd]' --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This script:

```
var host = '127.0.0.1';
var port = '27017';
var user = 'admin';
var pwd = 'secrets';
var authDB = 'admin';

try {
    var conn = new Mongo('mongodb://' + host + ':' + port + '/' + authDB);
    conn.auth({
        user: user,
        pwd: pwd,
        mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
        digest: false
    });

    // deletion commands...
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

gives this error:

```
$ mongo erasure.js
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
Error: Authentication failed.
```

Changing the `auth` part to this:

```
    conn.auth({
        user: user,
        pwd: pwd,
        mechanism: 'MONGODB-CR',
        db: authDB,
        digest: false
    });
```

gives me this error:

```
$ mongo erasure.js
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
Error: auth failed
```

The official documentation on [writing MongoDB scripts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) and [authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.auth/#db.auth) is also very scarce on how to do this.

How can I get the auth to work?

Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation linked, that's how you initiate a connection to the MongoDB server.

Comment: > From the mongo shell or from a JavaScript file, you can instantiate database connections using the Mongo() constructor:

Comment: Why are you trying to do a connection within the scripting itself? Unless you use `--nodb` then the shell is connecting to the database anyway, and all you need do is switch to the `admin` database and do `db.auth()` with valid options. Also if this is for anything other than a "one shot" purpose, then it would be advisable to use a fully fledged programming language instead. The shell is really just for prototyping and testing queries and other convenience "admin" functions. It was never intended to be a fully fledged environment.

Comment: Hey Neil! Okay, I'm not that familiar with MongoDB. I though what I was doing was basically like writing an SQL script. All I want to do is write a few batch statements. Byt you say "do `db.auth()` with valid options". What should I change? I know my password is correct.